# Laravel: Join Closure Inside where closure. Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm trying to select some registries in my "properties" table using a filter search function.

In my controller I receive the filters and process them with an advanced where, inside it I need to look registries related by other table when the filter "room" is used. For this I'm trying to do a join inside the where closure, but the join is not working at all, the search is done ignoring the join.

Controller:

```
        $filter_type= Input::has('filter_type') ? Input::get('filter_type') : NULL;
    $filter_val= Input::has('filter_val') ? Input::get('filter_val') : NULL;

    $state= NULL;
    $sub_category= NULL;
    $cat_operation= NULL;
    $room= NULL;

    if($filter_type == 'state'){
        $state                   = $filter_val;
    }

    if($filter_type == 'sub_category'){
        $sub_category            = $filter_val;
    }

    if($filter_type == 'cat_operation'){
        $cat_operation           = $filter_val;
    }

    if($filter_type == 'room'){
        $room                    = $filter_val;
    }

    $properties = Property::where(function($query) use ($state, $sub_category, $cat_operation, $room){

        if (isset($state)){
            $query->where('state_id', $state);
        }

        if (isset($sub_category)){
            $query->where('sub_category_id', $sub_category);
        }

        if (isset($cat_operation)){
            $query->where('cat_operation_id', $cat_operation);
        }

        if(isset($room)){

            $query->join('properties_control', function($join) use ($room)
            {
                if($room == 5){
                    $join->on('properties.id', '=', 'properties_control.property_id')
                         ->where('properties_control.category_feature_item_id', '=', 75)
                         ->where('properties_control.category_feature_item_value', '>=', $room);
                }else{
                    $join->on('properties.id', '=', 'properties_control.property_id')
                         ->where('properties_control.category_feature_item_id', '=', 75)
                         ->where('properties_control.category_feature_item_value', '=', $room);
                }
            });

        }

    })->paginate(20);
```

The join statement is not running at all.

It's possible include a join closure in a where closure like I am trying to do here? There is another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The main reason why your join closure is not working, is because it is enclosed in an advanced `where` closure.

Here's the laravel (right) way to write the code above:

```
$filter_type= Input::get('filter_type',null);
$filter_val= Input::get('filter_val',null);

//Start the query builder

$queryProperties = Property::newQuery();

//Switch on type of filter we received
switch($filter_type)
{
    case 'state'
        $queryProperties->where('state_id',$filter_val);
        break;
    case 'sub_category':
        $queryProperties->where('sub_category_id', $filter_val);
        break;
    case 'cat_operation':
        $queryProperties->where('cat_operation_id', $filter_val);
        break;
    case 'room':
        $queryProperties->join('properties_control', function($join) use ($filter_val)
        {
            if($room == 5){
                $join->on('properties.id', '=', 'properties_control.property_id')
                     ->where('properties_control.category_feature_item_id', '=', 75)
                     ->where('properties_control.category_feature_item_value', '>=', $filter_val);
            }else{
                $join->on('properties.id', '=', 'properties_control.property_id')
                     ->where('properties_control.category_feature_item_id', '=', 75)
                     ->where('properties_control.category_feature_item_value', '=', $filter_val);
            }
        });        
        break;
}

$properties = $queryProperties->paginate(20);
```